# Tasty, lovely, delicious, yummy, ...?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference, register

I know different English words for good tasting foods or drinks: *tasty*, *lovely*, *delicious*, *yummy*... But unfortunately the dictionary entries do not enable me to decide which one to use in which situation.

*Delicious* seems to be a "grown-ups' word", *yummy* a word of child speak: is that correct? What about *tasty* and *lovely*? Are there other words with this meaning? Which word should I use for an one-word-exclamation that I like the taste of the food/drink?

Comment: *scrumptious* is also a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delicious is adult/formal and a safe choice; yummy is childish; tasty and lovely are less formal.

Depending on who you are with, you might notice that English people are much less likely to make a one-word exclamation about food than people from other cultures.